# Multi-thread program in C - assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, multithreading

Trying to get the output to be something like this in a Unix environment:

Thread 0 - 0, Thread 1 - 0, Thread 2 - 0, Thread 2 - 1, Thread 2 - 2,
 Thread 3 - 0, ...

I'm sure that main() is fine, however this is my first time working with function pointers. I may be making some obvious mistakes. In summary...help.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
struct thread_data {
    int id;
};

typedef int (*Start) (void runner(void *), struct thread_data *params, pthread_t *thread);
typedef int (*Join) (int id); 

typedef struct _Thread {
    pthread_t id;
    Start start;
    Join join;
} Thread;

void runner();
int *start(void runner(void *), pthread_t* params, Thread *thread); 
int *join(int id);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(0));

    int i, num = 4;
    struct thread_data params[num];
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) params[i].id = i;

    Thread thread[num];
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        thread[i].start = start;
        thread[i].join = join;
    }

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        thread[i].start(runner, &params[i], &thread[i].id);
    }

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        thread[i].join(thread[i].id);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
void runner(){
        struct thread_data *data;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                printf("Thread %d - %d\n", data->id, i);
                sleep((int) (rand()%2));
        }
}
int *start(void runner(void *), pthread_t* params, Thread *thread){
    pthread_create(&thread->id, NULL, runner(void *), &params);
}

int *join (int id){ 
    pthread_join(id, NULL); //thread->id, NULL)
}
```

but am getting these errors

```
temp03.c: In function ‘main’:
temp03.c:30: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
temp03.c:31: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
temp03.c: In function ‘start’:
temp03.c:51: error: expected expression before ‘void’
temp03.c:51: error: invalid use of void expression
```

30 & 31 are the thread[i]... ones and 51 is the last one

```
Thread thread[num];
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    thread[i].start = start;
    thread[i].join = join;
}

int *start(void runner(void *), pthread_t* params, Thread *thread){
    pthread_create(&thread->id, NULL, runner(void *), &params);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind extracting lines *30*, *31* and *51* or pointing out which ones are they.

Comment: Surely this warning has nothing to do with the fact the program is multithreaded.

Comment: There are no line numbers in SO code blocks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show *where* the errors are (with comments in the code). And note that you declare both `start` and `join` to return values, but you never do. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Not to mention that you have a pointer `data` in the `runner` function, a pointer you never initialize but still dereference.

Comment: I found the lines, as this question is asking about the error/warning message I gave an answer. But you should take care of what the others commented.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function pointers are meant to return `int` while the functions return `int *`.

   There is effectively a type mismatch, you either

   - Change the function types defintions to return `int *`

     ```
     typedef int *(*Start) (void runner(void *), struct thread_data *params, pthread_t *thread);
     typedef int *(*Join) (int id);
     ```
   - Or fix the functions to return `int`

     ```
     int start(void runner(void *), pthread_t* params, Thread *thread); 
     int join(int id);
     ```

   It depends, on what you **really** need.
2. Your `runner` parameter is another function pointer apparently, but it's not declared as such, you have to fix it by writing something like

   ```
   typedef int *(*Start) (void (*runner)(void *), ... )
   ```

   instead.

   Fixing the definitions too of course.